# How to get the difference in texts by words?

Tags: go

I want to use library  https://github.com/sergi/go-diff

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sergi/go-diff/diffmatchpatch"
)

func main() {
    dmp := diffmatchpatch.New()
    text1 := "some text"
    text2 := "other text"
    diffs := dmp.DiffMain(text1, text2, true)
    fmt.Println(diffs)

}
```

output:

```
[{Delete s} {Equal o} {Delete m} {Insert th} {Equal e} {Insert r} {Equal  text}]
```

i wont:

```
[{Delete some}  {Insert other} {Equal  text}]
```

Is it possible?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/sergi/go-diff/diffmatchpatch"
)

func main() {
    dmp := diffmatchpatch.New()
    text1 := "some text"
    text2 := "other text"

    diffs := dmp.DiffMain(text1, text2, true)
    fmt.Println(dmp.DiffCleanupSemantic(diffs))
}
```